# Image upload and display within a docker environment

Tags: image, file, jsp, docker

I've been having some trouble now for a little while getting an image to display which is stored inside of a docker directory.

I am creating the directory inside of the dockerfile like so:

ENV IMG_PATH=/bacon/images
RUN mkdir -p $IMG_PATH
RUN chmod -R 777 $IMG_PATH

The code I have which is being used to save the file to the directory is:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*,java.util.zip.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <%
String saveFile="";
String contentType = request.getContentType();
if((contentType != null)&&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)){
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream()); //input stream
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
out.println("Form Data Length: " +formDataLength);
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while(totalBytesRead < formDataLength){
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}
String file = new String(dataBytes,"CP1256");
saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
out.println("Save File: " +saveFile);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
out.println("Save File: " +saveFile);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
out.println("Save File: " +saveFile);
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
int pos;
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes("CP1256")).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes("CP1256")).length;

File ff = new File("/bacon/images/"+saveFile);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
}
%>
```

I'm sure this is working as when testing with:

```
File f = new File("/bacon/images/"+imageId);
out.println(f.isFile()); // --> returns boolean
```

Which does return as true after I upload the file.

I am trying to display the image with:

```
<img class="thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Bootstrap template"   src="getImage.jsp?imageId=1 (1).png">
```

Which calls:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="windows-1252"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%@page import="java.io.File, org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64,org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils, java.io.IOException"%>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
String imageId = request.getParameter("imageId");
File f = new File("/bacon/images/"+imageId);
try{
byte[] pictureBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f));
response.setContentType("image/png");
response.getOutputStream().write(pictureBytes);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
}  
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();

        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's being display is:
[https://www.screencast.com/t/SgQFsKkKdX2s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3tTQ.png)

Giving a 200 okay: [200 okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RdEd.png)

Any help on this would be much appreciated, let me know if any bits need more detail or anything!

Thanks!

Fixed by changing to:

```
String imageId = request.getParameter("imageId");
File f = new File("/bacon/images/"+imageId);
//out.println(f.isFile());
try{
//byte[] pictureBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f));
byte[] pictureBytes = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setContentLength(pictureBytes.length); // imageBytes - image in bytes
response.getOutputStream().write(pictureBytes);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    out.println("error");
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing to:

```
String imageId = request.getParameter("imageId");
File f = new File("/bacon/images/"+imageId);
//out.println(f.isFile());
try{
//byte[] pictureBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f));
byte[] pictureBytes = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setContentLength(pictureBytes.length); // imageBytes - image in bytes
response.getOutputStream().write(pictureBytes);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    out.println("error");
}
```